# How do I concatenate ONLY the files in a directory?

Tags: linux

I want to concatenate all files excluding the directories inside a directory.

I tried to do

```
cat * | wc -l
```

to get the lines of the concatenated files, but I failed to exclude the directories.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Someone asked the same question elsewhere. Have a look: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48492/list-only-regular-files-but-not-directories-in-current-directory

Answer (score 2):

`cat` will automatically skip directories, so the number you get is already correct. The only thing is the warnings you get saying it skips them, but you can redirect those to `/dev/null`:

```
cat * 2> /dev/null | wc -l
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to designate a directory on this line? For example, I want to make these two lines into a one-liner: cd ~/data/email/spam;
cat * 2> /dev/null | wc -l

Comment: And also I am not quite sure why you did " 2 * "

Comment: `cat ~/data/email/spam/* 2> /dev/null | wc -l`  2 is the file descriptor number of stderr and should not be changed

Answer (score 1):

You can use find, for example:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 0 | xargs cat| wc -l
```